# Good php editor

Tags: php, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good PHP editors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4246/what-are-some-good-php-editors)

i have seen through other questions on the topic but most are a bit old. I looking for a good editor for developing on PHP in Linux(ubuntu). Here is my requirements

1. Basic editor features
2. Free
3. Light-Weight
4. Syntax highlighting
5. Code Folding (class,function,if/else/while/foreach block)
6. Code completion
7. Invalid Syntax/Error highlighting as you type
8. Auto code intending
9. Snippet support(pieces of custom or language specific codes that i can insert)
10. Extendable support

It would be great if it had the following

1. Debugging support
2. WYSIWYG
3. Code formatting
4. Framework support(cakephp/yii/zend/smarty)
5. Testing support
6. Todo
7. Native look and feel(Gnome)
8. Flex/ROR support is welcome but not a requirement
9. Mysql support

I have tried the following editors

1. Netbeans - it bloated, resource hogging and doesnt not have a native look and feel.
2. Eclipse is okay but i cant fold if/while blocks and slow.
3. Gedit can be extended and i have tried it but still i could not fold code or show error.

I currently use Geany but it doesn't inform me of syntax errors as i type. If you have ways to solve the problems with above editors they too are also welcome