# what php editor is good for development?

Tags: editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good PHP editors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4246/what-are-some-good-php-editors)

I installed the Ubuntu. can anyone suggest the good php editor for me, also have check in and check out function is better? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my option, Vim is the best editor for anything. I use it for python, shell script, c++, php, simple txt files etc. Vim is high configurable and it makes you a whole lot more productive. It takes some time to learn how to use it but believe me, it worth. You can install it using Ubuntu Software Center or download from the official site http://www.vim.org.

Answer (score 0):

I will list some of the popular code editing software in Ubuntu that you can use..

First of all, you can use the `GPHPedit` that available throught the Ubuntu repository. Open the Ubuntu Software Center and look for it.

You can use the `NetBeans`. It is also available from the Ubuntu Repository. Netbeans is a modular-type programming application which is support a lot of programming language with the help of the extra plugins. It also has the nice and understandable GUI.Extra infos will be available here...

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Netbeans
```

My favourite is the `Sublime Text2` (works well in Ubuntu, but can't work in the Kubuntu)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sublime-text-2
```

Sublime Text2 have the good appearance and it also has the good-to-look syntax highlighting...

Comment: How about the check in and check out function , because i will work in team!

Comment: please provide an example for the check in and check function... let see if I can help more~

Comment: like the visual studio team foundation server , when one person is editing the file, the other cannot be modi, until the person is check out, but the file will not update to the other immediately, it will wait until the other run the update.

Comment: ouh... sorry, I don't know about the check in and check out function. Maybe it is not available from the Sublime Text2 or GPHPedit, but you can try your luck using the Netbeans.... or another one called as Eclipse.Have a good luck. Hoping that I'm helping...

Comment: well, if you a working in team, when you are modify the coding , how about the other person? can they also modify or not ?

Comment: I'm not yet coding in team.... I work alone just now and do some minimal edits on some php files. Not really serious coding stuff and just depend on the Sublime Text2 only... sorry if you can't find your needs

Answer (score 0):

I use netbeans and eclipse for all my editing needs: PHP, Java, CSS, Ruby, etc.  They both require JRE/JDK to be installed, but that will be done automatically when you install from the software center.

They both support svn, git, cvs and many other version control system.  that will have to be configured separately, but easy to understand instructions are there.

I use these two editors because I switch between windows at work and linux at home, and these two IDEs are available for both platforms and work the same.

of the two netbeans is less confusing to start using.

Comment: So~ which one is better ?

Comment: it is not the tool, but the skill in using the tool.  people who are skilled make stuff look easy.  the skill itself takes practice.  pick one and start practicing.