# Ubuntu's best utilities for programmers

Tags: 15.04, application-development, programming

I have been working in Windows for many years, now I'm interested in using a Linux OS, so I am starting with Ubuntu. Can any experts recommend some apps that will help in programming?

### My programming skills:

**Server side:** 
PHP, Python, ASP

**Client Side:**
 HTML, CSS, JS, jQuery, AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu has default support for python. and you can run python codes in terminal using `python filename.py`.

PHP - `PHPStorm` [For more here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4246/what-are-some-good-php-editors)

python has a command shell - `Ipython`

ASP.NET - `MonoDevelop`

HTML, CSS, JS, JQUERY, AJAX - `Aptana, Kompozer, Intel XDK`

Text Editors - `Sublime Text, Komodo Edit, Atom`

I think my answer is helpful for you.
Thank you